# Getting desirable JMeter reports from java code

Tags: java, jmeter, report

Currently I'm struggling with getting desirable JMeter reports from java code. 
My goal is to get latency and throughput logged into file for each transaction and then have a summary per each scenario with averages and max/min values for latency and throughput.

Currently I have this code for reports:

```
ResultCollector csvlogger = new ResultCollector(summer);
csvlogger.setFilename(csvLogFile);
testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], csvlogger);
```

But in this way it logs info only per one transaction and there is no throughput, and latency reported is simply 0 (without any decimal part). 
It looks like this:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
2017/06/28 08:53:49.276,1014,Jedis Sampler,200,OK,Jedis Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,0,0,1,1,0,0,0
```

Does anyone know is there any way how I can tune it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- `only per one transaction` - .jtl log file contains execution of single sampler, try adding more threads and/or loops on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level and you should see more results.
- Latency always zero for scripting-based samplers, you need to explicitly call [SampleResult.setLatency()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setLatency-long-)  method and set the desired value.
- Throughput is not being recorded, it is being **calculated**. You need to open .jtl results file with i.e. [Aggregate Report](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-2-listeners-aggregate-data-samples?utm_source=BM&utm_medium=BM_blog&utm_campaign=jmeter-listeners-part3-calculate-distribution-metrics) or [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) listener to see the generated value. Take a look into [org.apache.jmeter.util.Calculator](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) class source to see the details if you prefer programmaticall non-GUI approaches.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dmitri, for you help! I really appreciate all your answers :) Now I'm struggling with how to get SampleResult? I'm kinda running circle... SampleResult sampleResult = new SampleResult(); SampleEvent sampleEvent = new SampleEvent(sampleResult, threadGroup.toString()); sampleResult = sampleEvent.getResult();
Is there any correct way how I can get it? Either SampleResult or SampleEvent